# Exception re-entered error when reading cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to save a id of my Quotation model and store it in a cookie on my controller. But when I try to read the cookie rails displays a exception reentered error.

```
class BasicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_cookie

  def quotations
    if params[:quotation]
      @quotation = Quotation.new( params.require(:quotation).permit(:author_name, :quote, :category) )

      if @quotation.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Quotation was successfully created.'
        Quotation.new
      end
    else
      @quotation = Quotation.new
    end

    if params[:sort_by] == "date"
      @quotations = Quotation.order(:created_at)
    else
      @quotations = Quotation.order(:category)
    end
  end

  def get_search
    @quotations = Quotation.all

    if params[:search]
      @quotations = Quotation.search(params[:search])
    else
      @quotations = Quotation.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  def cookies
    id = params[:id]
    @removed_id = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    cookies[:removed_id] = @removed_id
    redirect_to basics_quotations_path
  end

  private
  def get_cookie
    cookies.delete :test
    # @removed_ids = Array.new
    puts @removed_ids.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: Sort out your indentation.

Comment: Why are you storing the id in the cookie? What are you actually trying to do? I can't help but think there is a better way.

Comment: I am storing the id in the cookie so that when a user deletes the quotation with that id i can then choose to not load that quotation for that specific user with the id from the cookie.

sorry for bad code indentations

Comment: When you destroy a quotation, you should be able to redirect to a list of the user's quotations, and the destroyed quotation will no longer be displayed because it is gone. Whatever you are trying to do, there is no need to store the id in a cookie.